# Elastic beanstalk deploy fails when deploying more than 4 containers using docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having this weird issue with elastic beanstalk. I am using docker compose to run multiple docker containers on same elastic beanstalk instance.

if I run 4 docker containers everything works fine. but if i make it 5, deploy fails with error `Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed`.
and if I check eb-engine.log. it retries to `docker pull` command and fails with error.

this is really weird error.
bcs all docker images are valid and correctly tagged. it just the number of services that I am adding in docker compose file. if number is greater than 4, deploy fails

my question is,
is there any limit of docker services that can be run using docker compose ? or is there any timeout in elastic beanstalk to pull images?

Comment: Maybe there is no more space to run 5 contains on your instance? Did you check with larger one?

Comment: yeah I increased the volume size to 16GB which was 8GB by default but still it has same issue.

Comment: What instance are you using? t2.micro? Changing volume size does no do much, unless you extend partitions manually yourself.

Comment: alright, I just changed t2.micro to t2.large and it worked. thats really weird, is something with ram and cpu.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that `t2.micro` instance was used. The instance has only 1 vCPu and 1GB of ram. This was not enough to run 5 docker containers. Changing instance type to `t2.large` with 8GB ram and 2 vCPUs **solved** the problem.

docker-compose allows to specify cpu and memory [limits](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#resources). Maybe you can set them up to keep your containers resource requirements in check.